# Stapling feature from different project

Tags: feature-stapling

We have 2 projects in visual studio.

Project 1 has 2 features.

```
        Feature A is site scoped module 
        Feature B is web application scoped feature stapler. (empty element with FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation)
```

Project 2 has 1 feature (Feature X) that deploys list.

I want to staple the feature X to Feature B. So I am putting the feature id of feature X into the empty element (Feature B) of Project 1 as: `<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="IDofFeatureX" TemplateName="GLOBAL" />`

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is n o restriction as such that both the features should be in same project. It is always good practice to keep a separate project for site columns/content types/List & Libraries.Below are the points to be kept in mind while creating feature stapling:

1. Staplee feature should be having higher scope than stapled feature. eg: if stapled feature is site collection or web scope , then staplee feature should be web app scoped.
2. Since you are trying to activate the feature in every template ie TemplateName="GLOBAL" , it is helpful to understand about the **AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations** property of templates. If this property is set to **FALSE**, global association features will not be activated.So for such templates you will have to explicitly add **FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation** .Shared Services Provider site template and the Blank Site site template use the AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations="FALSE" property.
   Read this [blog](http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1075&page=2) for more info.